# jQuery error - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery beginning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="type/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <p onclick="$(this).hide();">Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html file. I have placed the downloaded js file in js folder inside the folder which is containing the above HTML file.

I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, when I click on "Test," instead of its being hidden.

Comment: Make sure you have entered correct path location.

Comment: am a beginner,,could you please specify how to fix this

Comment: @ShaunakD it is working this way as well https://jsfiddle.net/qmsq3Lqr/

Comment: If you go to view page source and then click on `jquery.js`. If it is showing that **file not found** then file is not included.

Comment: @ShaunakD it still works, what does that mean btw?

Comment: @erkaner Ahh yes, you re. Sorry. Im on my phone and the fiddle did not work.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner i can open js file by view source option..But still not working

Answer (score 3):

This means `jQuery.js` cannot be found at `js/jquery.js`. The file must be nonexistent or in another directory. You should check whether it is indeed called `jQuery.js` instead of something like `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`. If you cannot move it to the correct place, consider using the jQuery CDN:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Also, the use of inline JavaScript is **extremely** discouraged. You should make another script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("p").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: using <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> works great..but i can open js file by view source option....what was problem in my previous code

Comment: @Anonymous if you include the code I wrote above, but continue to use your `<script src="js/...`, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include jquery.min.js to your directory and page to implement jquery functionality.

you can include it as follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

else you can give local directory path for the same,This path should be specific, like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then implement your code in :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         // Your code here
    });
</script>
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery beginning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p id="para" onClick="$(this).hide();">Test</p>
</body>
</html>

use this ....................
```